# tangent space over what field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry

I know tangent space  at a point p on a manifold M  is a vector space.
But if it is a vector space then over what field?
Is the field M?

Thanks

Comment: The field is the reals. $M$ is not a field.

Comment: The earth (a sphere) is a manifold $M$. At a point $p \in M$ it looks 2-dimensional and flat (you can draw a local chart that is approximately flat). Note vectors $\vec{pq}, p,q\in M$ aren't well-defined (think to $p,q$ the north and south pole). But for any object moving on $M$ and passing through $p$, you can look at its "speed vector". Then those speed vectors are in a vector space : the tangent space $T_p M$ at $p$, which is a real vector space isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Manifolds are often described as "locally Euclidean". The "Euclidean" part refers to $\Bbb R^n$, which is a vector space over $\Bbb R$.